# version upgrade from 14.04 to 14.10 / Ubuntu tutorial for beginners

Tags: upgrade

When I installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS, to upgrade to the latest version (14.10), I
    used the following terminal commands:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade 
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

After I finished this, it seems strange to me:
I did not need to download the newest Ubuntu iso file and install it,
I have just typed these terminal commands!

Is this right?

Comment: Hi and welcome on AskUbuntu :-D Would you please split your question up and open a new one for the tutorial request? Btw I am not sure whether that would not be of-topic or too broad and therefore get closed anyway. You might find out on this yourself, google is your friend!

Comment: You are mixing 2 possible methodes: the ISO is only needed if you -reinstall- Ubuntu not for upgrading.

Answer (score 1):

The commands you posted above are not enough to change to a newer release of the distro.
The recommended command to move to a new release is:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

This should start the process of downloading and installing the new release version, however it will only move to a stable release. If the release you want to move to is still classed as in the development stage, you'll need to append the -d option.

If you want to check which version is currently installed on your system use:

```
lsb_release -a
```

This will produce a 5 line output, detailing which exact version of Ubuntu you're using, don't panic when the output starts with the line 'No LSB modules are available', that's perfectly normal.

So your best move is to use the lsb command first to check what version you're on, then if it still says 14.04, issue the do-release-upgrade command. Hope that helps!

Comment: so in order to upgrade newest version through the terminal. type the command : sudo apt-get update, sudo apt-get upgrade, sudo apt-get dist-upgrade, sudo do-release-upgrade ( or append -d) is that enough?